# Add role when react to emoji discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, roles, emoji

im trying to add a role when the user react to this emojis but i cant get

## Setup Roles

```
@bot.command()
async def roles(ctx):
    global IDMessage
    reaction   = await ctx.reply("Select your Game" + '\n' + '\n' + "- Valorant ‍♀️" '\n' + "- World of Warcraft ⚔" + '\n' + "- League of Legends ‍♀️" + '\n' + "- Cs:Go ")
    

    await reaction.add_reaction('‍♀️')
    await reaction.add_reaction('⚔')
    await reaction.add_reaction('‍♀️')
    await reaction.add_reaction('')
    
    IDMessage = reaction.message_id
```

And this is the part of the code that doesnt work for me

## Add role on reaction

```
@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
  ChID = '920320584032870424'
  if reaction.message.channel.id != ChID:
    return
  if reaction.emoji == "‍♀️":
    Valorant = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="Valorant")
    await bot.add_roles(user, Valorant)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues here. Instead of `on_reaction_add`, use `on_raw_reaction_add`. Most bots use the latter instead of the former.
Why you may ask? Because, `on_reaction_add` only works for messages in bot's cache.

So every message sent after your bot can read messages is stored in a dictionary or list (this is what a cache is). By default the limit of caching is `1000` messages.

So if you ever restarted your bot, the message will never be in cache, and thus the event won't trigger.

Another issue is that you are comparing a string (`ChID`) variable and an integer (`reaction.message.channel.id`), they can never be equal so `if reaction.message.channel.id != ChID` will always return True and thus won't do anything (as you return for that condition being True).

Third issue is that `bot.add_roles` does not exist. `add_roles` is a method of `discord.Member` object.

Fourth issue is, `Member.server` is not a thing, `Member.guild` is

So your updated code will be like:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload: discord.RawReactionActionEvent):
  ChID = 920320584032870424
  if payload.channel.id != ChID:
    return
  if str(payload.emoji) == "‍♀️":
    valorant = discord.utils.get(payload.member.guild.roles, name="Valorant")
    await payload.member.add_roles(valorant)
```

Also my personal advice of not using `global`
there are very rare few cases where you would actually require this keyword

But it is highly unlikely for you to use this in a bot made with `discord.py` lib

More on this:

- [`discord.on_reaction_add`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add)
- [`discord.RawReactionActionEvent`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.RawReactionActionEvent)
- [`discord.Member.guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.guild)
- [`discord.Member.add_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles)
- [why-are-global-variables-evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)

Answer (score 2):

ChID = `'920320584032870424'` (string) is being compared to an integer `reaction.message.channel.id`.

```py
  ChID = '920320584032870424'
```

Instead, use

```py
  ChID = 920320584032870424
```

Which is an integer.

Comment: Didn´t work for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and this is how I solved it.

You have the reactions being added, now you need to wait for the user to react.

For this, you can use discord.py’s wait_for function.

Check function:

```
def check(reaction):
    if str(reaction.emoji) == “EMOJIHERE”:
        return “emoji name”
    elif str(reaction.emoji) == “SECONDEMOJI”:
        return “emoji name”
    elif str(reaction.emoji) == “THIRDEMOJI”:
        return “emoji name”
    elif str(reaction.emoji) == “FOURTHEMOJI”:
        return “emoji name”
    else:
        return “error”
```

Code:

```
async def roles(ctx):
    global IDMessage
    reaction   = await ctx.reply("Select your Game" + '\n' + '\n' + "- Valorant ‍♀️" '\n' + "- World of Warcraft ⚔" + '\n' + "- League of Legends ‍♀️" + '\n' + "- Cs:Go ")
    

    await reaction.add_reaction('‍♀️')
    await reaction.add_reaction('⚔')
    await reaction.add_reaction('‍♀️')
    await reaction.add_reaction('')
    
    confirm = await bot.wait_for(“reaction_add”, check=check)
    if confirm == "emoji name 1":
        doSomething()
    elif confirm == "emoji name 2":
        doSomething()
    elif confirm == "emoji name 3":
        doSomething()
    elif confirm == "emoji name 4":
        doSomething()
    else:
        print("Error")
        await ctx.send("An error occurred.")
```

Replace EMOJIHERE and emoji name with the appropriate values.

Answer (score -1):

```py
##Embedd##

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def roles(ctx):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Server Roles", description="roles you can pick", color = discord.Colour.green())
        embed.add_field(name="**NOTIFICATIONS**", value="\n", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="**STREAMER**", value="\n", inline=True)
        embed.set_footer(text="Bot created by @FreakSheep#3267")
        embed.set_author(name='Flockersbot', icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/898921206420484108/1066931617643364433/Flockers_Bot.png')
        embed.set_thumbnail(url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/898921206420484108/1066931617643364433/Flockers_Bot.png')
        msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        msg = await msg.fetch() 
        await msg.add_reaction('')
        await msg.add_reaction('')

##Role React##

 if payload.emoji.name == "" and payload.message_id == 1066863494475034644:
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Streamer")
        if role is not None:
            member = discord.utils.find(lambda m: m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
            await member.add_roles(role)
```